# MS Access Link to Linked Tables in another databse

Tags: ms-access

Access-Database-1 on PC-1(WinXP) has number of linked tables to a legacy server.

Access-Database-2 on PC-2(Win10) wants to link to those tables in Access-Database-1 (PC-2 cannot directly communicate with Server).

However, when I try to use the External Data > Access Dabase Option, it only lists local tables in Database-1 and not those linked tables.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Sorry, you can't link to linked tables. The link that Jimmy provided tells the story!

Comment: Thanks, I will have to find some other way